# Is there a way to use authorize.net payment method in magento 2.3.3 and onwards versions?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net

I have a requirement in my magento community version 2.3.3 to use Authorize.net Direct post payment method, the magento 2 documentation in this link https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/authorize-net-direct-post.html says the magento core module for the Authorize.Net payment has been deprecated, so i also tried alternative module at this link https://marketplace.magento.com/authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet.html

So this module is also not working for me, so i need help if any alternate way to use Authorize.Net payment in Magento 2.3.3, Thanks

Following is my log trace of the error i am getting while testing payment using test credit card,

```
{"message":"The requested Payment Method is not available.","trace":"


0 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement->set('38958', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n


1 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('set', Array)\n


2 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('38958', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n


3 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Quote\/Model\/PaymentMethodManagement\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('set', Array, Array)\n


4 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/GuestCart\/GuestPaymentMethodManagement.php(49): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement\\Interceptor->set('38958', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n


5 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-checkout\/Model\/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(156): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\GuestCart\\GuestPaymentMethodManagement->set('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n


6 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


7 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n


8 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


9 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Checkout\/Model\/GuestPaymentInformationManagement\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n


10 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-checkout\/Model\/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(107): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformation('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


11 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


12 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n


13 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


14 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Checkout\/Model\/GuestPaymentInformationManagement\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n


15 [internal function]: Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('KBHQ9UrZ63XI6fA...', 'vishalr@magento...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n


16 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n


17 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n


18 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n


19 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n


20 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n


21 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n


22 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(137): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n


23 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n


24 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n


25 \/chroot\/home\/a4046dc9\/digisat.org\/html\/index.php(40): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n


26 {main}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i was searching for the solution for this mentioned issue and ended up with the following module : https://store.paradoxlabs.com/magento2-authorize-net-cim-payment-module.html

So i installed and configured this module in my magento community version 2.3.3 and tested payment using Authorize.net sandbox credentials and it worked perfectly for me,

If you looking for a sandbox authorize.net account then follow the link : https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox.html

Documentation of the extension is as follows:
https://store.paradoxlabs.com/media/wysiwyg/ParadoxLabs-CIM-user-manual.pdf