# Which Available Authorize.net Plugin is the "Official Extension"?

Tags: magento2.4, authorize.net

The Magento release notes for 2.4.0 state that:

> With this release, the Authorize.Net method integration has been
> removed from core code. Merchants should migrate to the **official
> extension** that is available on the Commerce Marketplace.

Looking on the Magento Marketplace there seems to be 4 options available:

[image: image showing available magento 2 authorize.net plugins]

I'm wondering which of these options are the "official extension" mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct Authorize.net has been deprecated by magento 2 so only module that did work for me was paradoxlabs module and you can either get it from magento marketplace or their own store, both works in Magento 2.4.x.

For more reference : [Authorize.net payment for magento 2.3.x and 2.4.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315099/87057)

Comment: Yep after reviewing all the options, ParadoxLabs was the only plugin vendor which was found in the [list of trusted partners on authorize.net](https://www.authorize.net/resources/find-a-partner/certified-solutions/paradoxlabs-inc.html?category=category-one). I ended up using this plugin. Thanks!